# Check SMTP server capabilities on the command line

Tags: command-line, smtp

I know an SMTP server's URL. I want to know about that SMTP server's capabilities: TLS, password encryption, etc. Evolution Mail knows how to report these. How can I get them from the command line?

**UPD**. EHLO output

```
EHLO yandex.ru
250111.localdomain.ru Hello ac60.localdomain.ru [172.16.2.60] (may be forged), pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

Comment: URL? smtp://servername?

Comment: Why close it and downvote?

Comment: Yes URL like this. But it is in my work intranet and don't accessible by foreign hosts...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**RFC 5321**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#page-17) defines this in section 3.2:

So basically you can send
**EHLO** which should be answered by the mailserver with a list of extended capabilities, including valid encryption algorithms.

Should the server not understand EHLO, it is propably an older system, that just accepts **HELO**. I did not read any further than this, whether the old systems can be asked about capabilities as well - but the provided links leads to the older SMTP-RFCs as well.

Comment: I updated main question with EHLO output. Did I use EHLO in proper way?

Comment: @petRUShka Yes, this is the first step, that shows that the mailserver is capable of STARTing Transaction Layer Security. For details see the WiKi about [STARTTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS). Basically you have to issue now **STARTTLS** eventually followed by another **EHLO**. The answer to STARTTLS should contain that cipher-list.

Answer (score 2):

You've given the answer in your question.  When you use the `EHLO` command, the server will respond with all the SMTP extensions that it supports.  So the server you are connecting to supports these extensions:

```
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

The only extension related to encryption is `STARTTLS`.